# Помогите написать запрос к SQL

Tags: sql

Подскажите как это правильно задать. Есть таблица, мне нужно высчитать пустые ячейки, для каждого пользователя.
[image: Таблица]

Comment: SQLite, я просто совсем в этом не понимаю, простой запрос  могу, но логику задать в данном случае, не хватает ума

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT name_user, COUNT(*) - COUNT(date) AS amount_of_NULLs
FROM tablename
GROUP BY 1;
```

Если пустая ячейка - это не NULL, а строка нулевой  длины, то

```sql
SELECT name_user, COUNT(*) - COUNT(NULLIF(date, '')) AS amount_of_empty_values
FROM tablename
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое